# Composer incorrectly creating symlinks in vendor/bin

Tags: php, composer-php, bamboo

When kicking off composer from an Atlassian Bamboo build plan, it creates a broken symlink in the vendor/bin directory preventing phpunit from being kicked off.

```
$ ls -al vendor/bin
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  2 bamboo bamboo 4096 Dec 19 16:33 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 bamboo bamboo 4096 Dec 19 16:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 bamboo bamboo   26 Dec 19 16:33 phpunit

$ cat vendor/bin/phpunit
../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Since it's creating a plain file containing the intended symlink target, I'm getting a permission denied on the part of the step that calls vendor/bin/phpunit.  If I ssh into the Bamboo instance and then run all of the build steps manually, then everything works fine.

I'm hoping this is a common enough issue with an easy fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out a team member committed their vendor folder, and had done some creative things with its contents.

Deleting the folder from the repository and rerunning the build did the trick.